# how to get sum of vowels in list in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, contains, fold

i need to get sum of vowels from list of strings with help function .fold

i tried:

```
val student = listOf("Sheldon", "Leonard", "Howard", "Raj", "Penny", "Amy", "Bernadette")

val vowels = setOf('a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O','y','Y','u','U')

val sumVowels = student.fold(0){acc, student, ->
if(student.contains(vowels)) acc + 1 else acc + 0
```

I don't know how to place vowels in .contains. Maybe I choose not the right way to solve the problem, but I should use `fold` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write

```
val sumVowels = student.fold(0){acc, s -> acc + s.count{it in vowels}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val list = listOf("Sheldon", "Leonard", "Howard", "Raj", "Penny", "Amy", "Bernadette")
val vowels = setOf('a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'y', 'Y', 'u', 'U')

val result = list
  .joinToString("")
  .count { char -> char in vowels }

println(result)   // Output: 16
```

Comment: While this is good code*, it doesn't strictly answer the question, which asked for a solution using `fold()`. (* Actually, I think I prefer the slightly more complex but more memory-efficient approach of `list.sumOf{ it.count{ it in vowels }}`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = listOf("Sheldon", "Leonard", "Howard", "Raj", "Penny", "Amy", "Bernadette")
val vowels = setOf('a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'y', 'Y', 'u', 'U')
var numberOfVowels = 0
list.forEach{s ->
   numberOfVowels += s.count{it in vowels}
}
println(numberOfVowels)

Output: 16
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).